# jQuery hidden checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to set this the way if "marketingAAA" is checked as true, a hidden checkbox "marketingPhone" is set as TRUE as well. This works.

However, if any other checkbox on the page is set to be TRUE, then it still goes TRUE for "marketingPhone". Can't figure this out why. It should stay as FALSE if "marketingAAA" is not checked TRUE. Does anyone see the issue?

```js
$(function() {
      var marketingAAA= $("input[type='checkbox']");
      var marketingPhone = $("input[type='hidden'][name='marketingPhone']");

    marketingAAA.on('change', function()
            {
            if ($(this).val() == "TRUE")  {
              marketingPhone.prop('checked',true);
              marketingPhone.val('TRUE');

    } else {
              marketingPhone.prop('checked',false);
              marketingPhone.val('FALSE');

     }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="marketingrules" name="marketingBBB" type="checkbox" class="radio-button-input" value="TRUE">

 <input id="marketing" name="marketingAAA" type="checkbox" class="radio-button-input" value="TRUE">

<input type="hidden" name="marketingPhone" value=""/>
```

Comment: `var marketingAAA= $("input[type='checkbox']");` is the issue here. You now select all checkboxes.

Comment: Why don't you use `$("#marketing")` and `$("#marketingrules")`?

Comment: if `marketingPhone` directly depends on `marketingAAA`, you can make use of `marketingAAA` value itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you should specify 'marketAAA'.

```
var marketingAAA= $("input[type='checkbox'][name='marketingAAA']");
```

Right now it checks all the checkboxes and if one is true it will check 'marketingPhone'.

```
$(function() {
  var marketingAAA= $("input[type='checkbox'][name='marketingAAA']");
  var marketingPhone = $("input[type='hidden'][name='marketingPhone']");

marketingAAA.on('change', function()
        {
        if ($(this).val() == "TRUE")  {
          marketingPhone.prop('checked',true);
          marketingPhone.val('TRUE');

} else {
          marketingPhone.prop('checked',false);
          marketingPhone.val('FALSE');

 }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you're selecting *all* the `[type="checkbox"]` elements. To fix this select the `marketingAAA` element only.

Note that in the example below I changed the hidden element to a `text` so that the effect is more easily visible. I also removed your setting of the `checked` property, as a `hidden` input does not have that.

```js
$(function() {
  var $marketingAAA = $("#marketing");
  var $marketingPhone = $("input[name='marketingPhone']");

  $marketingAAA.on('change', function() {
    $marketingPhone.val(this.checked ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="marketingrules" name="marketingBBB" type="checkbox" class="radio-button-input" value="TRUE">

<input id="marketing" name="marketingAAA" type="checkbox" class="radio-button-input" value="TRUE">
<input type="text" name="marketingPhone" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

set this var correctly

```
var marketingAAA= $("#marketing");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you define the variable marketingAAA in the script:

```
var marketingAAA= $("input[type='checkbox']");
```

In this way you are selecting all the checkboxes in the page, but you only want the marketingAAA.

So instead of selecting all checkboxes try to get the element by it's id:

```
var marketingAAA= $("#marketing");
```

Or by it's name like you did in the line after:

```
var marketingAAA = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='marketingAAA']");
```

Do remember that IDs in html should be unique!